# parsing xml containing &entities; with minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, entities, minidom

I'm trying to parse XML files using minidom.  This is simple in simple cases (`doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(fileName)`).  But I have XML containing named entities (e. g. `&uuml;`, `&agrave;` and similar, some are special and non-standard).

I think I still can use minidom but have to pass a proprietary parser (containing an entity resolver) when calling `xml.dom.minidom.parse(source, parser)` as second argument.  I cannot find any example for this.  Does anybody have a link or a small example for me which does this?

Comment: Some of my XML files contain DTD references which explain the used entities; therefor I'd be happy to use the EntityResolver (just don't know how).  Others do not contain such DTD references; for these I'd like to handle unknown entities (like `&blah;`) myself.  Is there such an option?

Comment: There's a hint on the minidom docs about an entity resolver, but no example.